Circle on a grid generated by canvas tkinter moves wrong way?
I have some logic up and running that controls how a circle moves through a Tkinter Canvas depending on which direction it is coming from, and I'm trying to make it act differently depending on whether the obstacle (1) is in the middle or the end. In this type of graph represented in canvas:
[

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

]

The circle moves to the first obstacle, dodges it by going down to the row below, moves right, down when it reaches the edge and right towards the next obstacle. This is expected.
But when it reaches the obstacle, it goes down then left? Instead of executing the "obstacle in the middle from left" method as planned.
What's wrong? I think there may be a conflict between the "obstacle at the end" and "no obstacle" functions.
#generate an environment, represented by Tkinter, consisting of
    #a matrix representing the room
    #1 and 0 will denote the presence of obstacles
import math
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import threading
 
matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
 
ROOM_WIDTH = 700
ROOM_HEIGHT = 700
SPACE_SIZE = 75
OBSTACLE_COLOR = "#ADD8E6"
FREE_COLOR = "#90EE90"
 
rows = 4
columns = 4
 
window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=ROOM_HEIGHT, width=ROOM_WIDTH)
 
direction_from = "begin_right"
 
class Bot:
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
        self.speed = 8
        self.x = ROOM_WIDTH // 8
        self.y = ROOM_HEIGHT // 8
        self.my_circle = canvas.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x + 30, self.y + 30)
        canvas.moveto(self.my_circle, 30, 40)
 
    def left(self):
        x = 0 - (self.speed)
        y = 0
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)
 
    def right(self):
        x = self.speed
        y = 0
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)
 
    def up(self):
        x = 0
        y = -self.speed
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)
 
    def down(self):
        x = 0
        y = 75 // 2
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)
 
    def check_collision(self):
        global direction_from
 
        mower_coords = canvas.coords(self.my_circle)
        center_x = (mower_coords[0] + mower_coords[2]) / 2
        center_y = (mower_coords[1] + mower_coords[3]) / 2
 
        for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for j, item in enumerate(row):
                x1, y1 = j * SPACE_SIZE, i * SPACE_SIZE
                x2, y2 = (j + 1) * SPACE_SIZE, (i + 1) * SPACE_SIZE
 
                #have two scenarios: obstacle at end and obstacle in middle
                if (x1 - 4 <= mower_coords[2] <= x1) and item == 1 and y1 < mower_coords[1] < y2:
                    #obstacle at end (the x value is close to 600 or 0)
                    if direction_from == "begin_right":
                        bot.down()
                        bot.down()
                        bot.left()
                        direction_from = "left"
                    elif direction_from == "right" and 0 <= mower_coords[0] <= 10:
                        bot.down()
                        bot.right()
                        direction_from = "left"
                    elif direction_from == "left" and 595 <= mower_coords[0] <= 600:
                        bot.down()
                        bot.left()
                        direction_from = "right"
                    #obstacle in middle
                    elif direction_from == "right":
                        bot.down()
                        bot.left()
                        bot.left()
                        bot.up()
                        bot.up()
                        bot.left()
                        direction_from = "left"
                    elif direction_from == "left":
                        bot.down()
                        bot.right()
                        bot.right()
                        bot.up()
                        bot.up()
                        bot.right()
                        direction_from = "right"
 
        # If no obstacle is encountered, continue moving in the current direction
        if direction_from == "begin_right":
            bot.right()
            print(mower_coords)
        elif direction_from == "left":
            bot.left()
        elif direction_from == "right":
            bot.right()
 
        #If end of room is reached
        if mower_coords[0] <= 10:
            bot.down()
            bot.right()
            direction_from = "right"
 
        print(mower_coords)
 
class Environment:
    def draw_matrix(matrix, canvas):
        # loop through matrix, assign color depending on value and create square
        for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for j, item in enumerate(row):
                x1, y1 = j * SPACE_SIZE, i * SPACE_SIZE
                x2, y2 = (j + 1) * SPACE_SIZE, (i + 1) * SPACE_SIZE
                color = OBSTACLE_COLOR if item == 1 else FREE_COLOR
                canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)
 
window.title("Robot lawnmower")
window.resizable(False, False)
 
Environment.draw_matrix(matrix, canvas)
 
bot = Bot()  # Create an instance of the Bot class
 
canvas.pack()
 
def run_collision_function():
    threading.Timer(0.1, run_collision_function).start()
    bot.check_collision()
 
run_collision_function()
 
window.mainloop()
 
# Bind the event handlers to the window
    # window.bind('<Left>', bot.left)
    # window.bind('<Right>', bot.right)
    # window.bind('<Up>', bot.up)
    # window.bind('<Down>', bot.down)

Thank you!

Hmm, I might have made a mistake with the coordinate boundaries.
